# Get address of a function which has variadic templates in C++11

Tags: c++11, g++

When saving the address of a function with a variadic template, the g++ compiler (Version 4.8.2) outputs this error:

> address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

The code in question:

```
template<typename... Args>
void redirect_function(const char *format, Args... args)
{
    pLog->Write(format, args...); // or: printf(format, args...);
}

void *fnPtr = (void *)&redirect_function; // The error occurs here.
```

Here is what I do with this somewhere else:

```
typedef void (*log_bridge)(const char*, ...);
log_bridge LogWrite;
LogWrite = (log_bridge)fnPtr;
```

I have no other possibility to this so please don't suggest completely different ways of solving this.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a different possibility, because this simply isn't possible. A function template is not a function, it's a template. A pointer to a function must refer to a function, not a function template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It is simple why it's not possible. You have a clear ambiguousity. `redirect_function` is not a function; as all template functions it's more like a set of overloads generated from the template for different types of arguments.

The function needs to get instantiated first to be able to get its address, and you provide no necessary information to do this.

In other words the problem is that you cannot possibly know which concrete overload of `redirect_function` you should use on the problematic line.

The only thing you could do is to provide template arguments explicitly.